# Using loops and lists

Tags: python-3.x

```
def input_list():
    first_list = []
    string_requested = input()
    while string_requested != [""]:
        new_list = first_list.append(string_requested)
```

Want to ask the user for a string and add it to the list and so on, so long as the string is not empty, why does it create an endless loop?

Comment: Want to ask the user for a string and add it to the list and so on, so long as the string is not empty, why does it create an endless loop?

Comment: You don't take new input inside the loop. Also note that new_list is never actually used (and is None anyway, append doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 1):

You have to read input *inside* the loop in order to fill the list with new input. ALso, as has been pointed out, `append` returns `None` and should not be assigned. Let alone, you never use `new_list` anyway. The following will work:

```
def input_list():
    new_list = []
    while True:
        string_requested = input()
        if string_requested == "":
            return new_list
        new_list.append(string_requested)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for adding the input value by the user to list until he enters an empty string. This might help you.

```
def input_list():
    first_list = []
    string_requested = input("enter string")
    first_list.append(string_requested)

    while len(string_requested) != 0:
        string_requested = input("enter string")
        if len(string_requested) != 0:            
            first_list.append(string_requested)
    print(first_list)

input_list()
```

Outputs:

```
enter string: One
enter string: Two
enter string: Three
enter string: FOur
enter string: 
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'FOur']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the full explanation!!
@Vineeth Sai!

Comment: Accept either of the answers so it is marked as solved.